# Android: query for albums gives duplicates

Tags: android, database, media

I'm querying the contentresolver in order to list all the albums on the device. However I have losts of duplicate. Is it a problem of my query or of the android database? 
Maybe is it because I'm getting albums from a songs' table?

```
String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST
            };

            String selection = null;

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    null,
                    null);
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190876/how-to-use-mediastore-query-to-get-artists-without-duplicates