# Android: How to list mp3 albums

Tags: android, mediastore

I want to try develop simple android music player. 
I have this method below to list album title, but it gives duplicate albums list.

```
    public void getAlbumList() {
    //query external audio
    Activity a=getActivity();
    ContentResolver musicResolver = a.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //String[] projection = null;

    //String sortOrder = null;

    String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";

    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3"); 

    String[] selectionArgsMp3 = new String[]{ mimeType };
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsMp3, null);
    //iterate over results if valid

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
        //get columns
        int atitleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        //int bitmap = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
            //  (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
        //add songs to list
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext()){
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisaTitle = musicCursor.getString(atitleColumn);

            albumList.add(new Album(thisId, thisaTitle));
        } 

    }
}
```

I have tried [How to use MediaStore query to get Artists without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190876/how-to-use-mediastore-query-to-get-artists-without-duplicates) but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is simply removing duplication an issue ?

Comment: Yes, I want to solve this issue first.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your Album class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Album) {
        Album album = (Album) obj;
        //here we compare if the 2 album objects are same or not (edit code as needed)
        return (album.getaTitle().equals(this.aTitle) && album.getId == this.Id);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hashcode = 0;
    hashcode = this.Id*20;
    hashcode += this.aTitle.hashCode();
    //here we generate the album object hashcode using Id and artistname 
    return hashcode;
}
```

then instead of adding your objects to a list, use this :

```
HashSet<Album> albumList = new HashSet<Album>();
albumList.add(new Album(thisId, thisaTitle));
//use simple for each loop to iterate
for(Album album:albumList){
            System.out.println(album);
        }
```

A hashset aromatically handles duplications

Comment: Why not use query or if iteration ? Is it not appropriate with my code ??

Comment: well you are already adding the album objects to a list, I assumed you don’t have to depend on query. That question you had linked clearly states duplications cant be removed with query alone.