# How to get the distinct element from mediastore by java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, distinct-values

I am trying to get the file names of all the audio files but I am getting same file names for multiple songs

1.I cannot use `DISTINCT` key word as I am getting the file names from `DATA` .

2.I am using the Mediastore.Files So the select it takes `MEDIA_TYPE` so this way is also not possible .

3 .I want to get the `Parent` value as distinct not the repeating value .

So the only way is by doing in java .I followed the method given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190876/how-to-use-mediastore-query-to-get-artists-without-duplicates) but I am not able to set

Here is a piece of my code

```
if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        int filetitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE);
        int file_id = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID);
        int fileparent = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT);
        int filedata = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
        Mediafileinfo info = new Mediafileinfo();

        info.setData(new File(new File(audioCursor.getString(filedata)).getParent()).getName());
        info.setTitle(audioCursor.getString(filetitle));
        info.set_id(audioCursor.getString(file_id));
        info.setParent(audioCursor.getString(fileparent));

        audioList.add(info);
    } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

How I can get the non repeating elements?? For more info [mediastore.file](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.html)
I am adding the data in Mediafileinfo class which contain getter and setter.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want. Is it just a string list of distinct parents of all the files? (the parent of a File is the folder where the file resides in). But why are you instantiating a Mediafileinfo instance for each found row?

Comment: @Heri see the update question

Comment: "as I am getting the file names from DATA" -- How exactly does that prevent DISTINCT usage? You could store a HashSet of the data that you have "seen", then don't do `audioList.add(info);` when that set contains that data

Comment: when using File.FileColumn the select option i have to select all the AUDIO_TYPE files so I can not use DISTINCT in select

Comment: You should be able to select all audio types and do DISTINCT on another column

Comment: Still not clear. If the distinct criteria is the parent (folder name) then which MediafileInfo do you want to be in the resulting set? There could be more than one file in a parent folder.

Comment: Mediafileinfo is a class for getter and setter and `PARENT` key word gives a numeric value for every file like an id where in mediastore.file you will get diff id for diff song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the Parent value as distinct not the repeating value .

Alright, you could use a `HashSet<String>` to maintain a list of seen `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT` values.

Not sure what was wrong with the SQL approach, though.

```
HashSet<String> seenParents = new HashSet<String>();

if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    final int fileparent = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT);
    do {
        String parent = audioCursor.getString(fileparent);

        Mediafileinfo info = new Mediafileinfo();
        // bla...
        info.setParent(parent);

        if (!seenParents.contains(parent)) { // prevents dups
            seenParents.add(parent);
            audioList.add(info);
        }

// end loop
```

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear which values you see as duplicates. My approach still applies, you just need to choose which field you'd like to prevent.

Comment: Getting the value thx and if i want to get non duplicate for parent and files then .I have to make two hashSet or one will work?

Comment: You can concatenate the name of the parent and the file together and add that string to the set instead of only the parent name