# How can I compare the string with the keys in hash map

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, hashtable

I am having difficulties to compare the string (`str`) with the keys in hashmap. As you can see from the below code, I have multiple keys. I am comparing the `str` with the keys but I couldn't get the values for that specific key. Please note the map contains `coin`.

**it works only if i directly input the string eg** `entry.getKey().getKeyOne().toString().contains("coin")`

```
String str = "coin";
for(Map.Entry<Pair, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getKey().getKeyOne().toString().contains(str)||
        entry.getKey().getKeyTwo().toString().contains(str)) {
            entry.getValue();
    }
}

public class Pair {
    private String keyOne;
    private String keyTwo;

    Pair(String one,String two) {
        this.keyOne=one;
        this.keyTwo=two;
    }

    public String getKeyOne() {
        return keyOne;
    }

    public String getKeyTwo() {
       return keyTwo;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is a `Pair`?

Comment: try this it is in android but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062224/how-to-get-the-distinct-element-from-mediastore-by-java

Comment: Can you post the toString implementation for KeyOne and KeyTwo if its your own class. If not please add the code for Pair as said earlier by Andrew.

Comment: Can you post how you init your HashMap? It is HashMap? Do you want something like: entry.getKey().contains("coin")?

Answer (score 1):

Advice: As long you are using your own class `Pair` in a `Map` you **must** override `equals()` and **should** override `hashCode()`.

<strike>You example with the string literal works, because "coin" is in the [string pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java) and all references the same String.</strike>

Runs here:

```
public class Pair {

    private String keyOne;
    private String keyTwo;

    Pair(String one, String two) {
        this.keyOne = one;
        this.keyTwo = two;

    }

    public String getKeyOne() {
        return keyOne;
    }

    public String getKeyTwo() {
        return keyTwo;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Pair, String> map = new HashMap();
        map.put(new Pair("coin", "5"), "U");
        map.put(new Pair("bill", "100"), "H");
        map.put(new Pair("10", "5coin"), "T");

        String str = new String("coin");
        for (Map.Entry<Pair, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().getKeyOne().toString().contains(str)
                    || entry.getKey().getKeyTwo().toString().contains(str)) {
                System.err.println(entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple sample code for you
If you want it for one Hashmap only

```
public void findInkeys(String findkey){
    HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<>();

    //Place your content of MAp Here
    //Start

    //end
    //or you can place your content anywhere else but make sure is is initialized before this


    Set<String> keys=map.keySet();
    boolean isInKeys=false;
    for (String k : keys)
    {
        if(k.equals(findkey))
        {
            isInKeys=true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isInKeys);
}
```

if you want it for any `hashmap`

```
public void findInkeys(HashMap<String,Object> map,String findkey){

    Set<String> keys=map.keySet();
    boolean isInKeys=false;
    for (String k : keys)
    {
        if(k.equals(findkey))
        {
            isInKeys=true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isInKeys);
}
```

if you have multiple Keys to compare then go with below code

```
public void findInkeys(HashMap<String, String> map,ArrayList<String> keyList){
    Set<String> keys=map.keySet();
    boolean isInKeys=false;
    for (String k : keys)
    {
        if(keyList.contains(k))
        {
            isInKeys=true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isInKeys);
}
```